# Java readUnsignedShort() explanation

Tags: java

Can someone explain the following code snippet, please?

```
 methodAttributeLength = (long)dis.readUnsignedShort() << 16 | dis.readUnsignedShort();
```

I checked this in java doc .But I can't get the idea. I know what the [`java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedShort()) method does.But the problem is that `<<16` thing.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataInputStream#readUnsignedShort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedShort--) return a `int` which spend 32 bits, but the `short` type spend 16 bits.

`int << 16` will shift the low 16 bits to high 16 bits and fills `0` in the low 16 bits. for example:

```
int value = 0b11111111000000001000000011111111;
                              ^---------------     
                int high  = 0b10000000111111110000000000000000;
                // high == value << 16
```

in this case, and the `|` operator is joins high bits and low bits together. for example:

```
int high  = 0b10000000111111110000000000000000; 
int low   = 0b00000000000000001000000000000001; 
int value = 0b10000000111111111000000000000001;
// value == high | low;
```

on the other hand, your protocol saving an `int` into two `short`s which are a high `short` and a low `short`. and the code above is read the `int` value from two `short`s.

for more details you can see [bitewise operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) and [shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

Comment: Can't we use `readInt()` for this purpose since it reads 4 bytes?

Comment: @Pegusus yes, `readInt` will read 4 bytes, however `readUnsignedShort` will read 2 bytes. and the `readInt` will result in negative numbers sometimes, but  `readUnsignedShort` is never.